# Swift iOS set a song from music library for UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, swift

I'm cloning the alarm application for iOS. But I don't know how to implement the "Pick a song" function of this app. 
"Pick a song" allow you to select music from Music Library and set that song for your alarm notification. I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Do I need to copy the selected song and copy it to my app?

Comment: This is way too broad. Please narrow down your question to one specific programming issue.

Comment: I just want to pick a song from music library, then use it for notification. That's all!

Comment: See `MPMediaPickerController`.

Comment: How to set the selected song to my app?